# Converting IStreamResult to RxJs Observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs, signalr

**The problam:**
Having installed `@microsoft/signalr` (Javascript/Typescript client for SignalR for ASP.NET Core), I've noticed that `HubConnection`  defines a method called `stream` that is used to invoke a streaming hub method on the server (using the specified name and arguments) and returns `IStreamResult` which described as:

> an API that is similar to Observable, but we don't want users to confuse it for that so we rename things. Someone could
> easily adapt it into the Rx interface if they wanted to. Unlike in C#, we can't just implement an "interface" and get extension methods for free. The methods have to actually be added to the object (there are no extension methods in JS!). We don't want to depend on RxJS in the core library, so instead we duplicate the minimum logic needed and then users can easily adapt these into
> proper RxJS observables if they want.

I've tried converting it to RxJs Observable using `from` operator but it turned out that the Subscription type (`ISubscription`)  defines a `dispose` method
rather than `unsubscribe`
 as explained in the following error:

> Type 'IStreamResult' is not assignable to type 'Subscribable'.
> The types returned by 'subscribe(...)' are incompatible between these types.
> Property 'unsubscribe' is missing in type 'ISubscription' but required in type 'Unsubscribable'

**The question:** 
How to properly convert `IStreamResult` to `Rxjs Observable`?

**IStreamResult (Observable):**

```
export interface IStreamResult<T> {
    subscribe(subscriber: IStreamSubscriber<T>): ISubscription<T>;
}
```

**IStreamSubscriber (Observer):**

```
export interface IStreamSubscriber<T> {
    /** A boolean that will be set by the {@link @microsoft/signalr.IStreamResult} when the stream is closed. */
    closed?: boolean;
    /** Called by the framework when a new item is available. */
    next(value: T): void;
    /** Called by the framework when an error has occurred.
     *
     * After this method is called, no additional methods on the {@link @microsoft/signalr.IStreamSubscriber} will be called.
     */
    error(err: any): void;
    /** Called by the framework when the end of the stream is reached.
     *
     * After this method is called, no additional methods on the {@link @microsoft/signalr.IStreamSubscriber} will be called.
     */
    complete(): void;
}
```

**ISubscription (Subscription):**

```
export interface ISubscription<T> {
    /** Disconnects the {@link @microsoft/signalr.IStreamSubscriber} associated with this subscription from the stream. */
    dispose(): void;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I dunno, never worked with IStreamResult before, but here's a start?

The simplest approach seems to be to subscribe to IStreamResult, then bind each callback function to an Observer on an Observable. That should pass the values/event with minimal work done via the wrapper observable.

This assumed IStreamResult behaves beneath the hood. For example, promises are eager instead of lazy, so `from(promise: Promise)` launches the promise before you subscribe and hands down the result immediately (or whenever it's ready).

Which, if you're used to lazy-execution observables can be very surprising. Most often I use `defer(() => promise:Promise)`, which launches the promise only when subscribed.

If IStreamResult has some atypical behaviour like that, it might take some digging to figure out as `fromIStreamResult` below does no checks for proper behaviour.

**Aside:** Not sure what to do about `closed?: boolean`...

---

```js
/**
 * Static operator to turn IStreamResult into Observable
 **/
function fromIStreamResult<T>(input: IStreamResult<T>): Observable<T> {
  return new Observable<T>(observer => {
    subscription = input.subscribe({
      next: observer.next.bind(observer),
      error: observer.error.bind(observer),
      complete: observer.complete.bind(observer)
    });
    return {
      unsubscribe: subscription.dispose.bind(subscription)
    }
  })
}
```

Then you can use `fromIStreamResult(iStream: IStreamResult)` the same way you'd use `from(promise: Promise)` and just begin transforming with RxJS operators.

Comment: Made a quick update to explain where this approach may fall short.

Comment: thank you for your nice answer! I thought there would be simpler solution...

Comment: @RafiHenig There very well might be! I've never been around `@microsoft/signalr`, but it wouldn't surprise me if they had some utility or ... something